# Speed of increase of moments ratio

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a unidimensional random variable $X$ with zero mean, I'm interested in the behavior of the moments ratio

$$r(k) = \frac{\mathbb E\left[|X|^{3k}\right]}{\mathbb E\left[|X|^{2k}\right]^{3/2}}$$

as $k$ becomes large.

If $X$ has a discrete distribution, then I found that $r(k)=O(1)$.

If $X$ has uniform distribution then I got $r(k)=O(\sqrt k)$. Is this true in general for continuous distributions with bounded support?

If $X$ is Gaussian then $r(k)$ grows exponentially. Is this true in general for continuous distributions with unbounded support?

Comment: I don't think so. Firstly, higher moments might be infinite (for power-laws, for example). Secondly, the survival function might die off very fast, making growth sub-exponential. It seems like you get exponential growth if pdf/survival function behaves like $\exp(-\Theta(x^\alpha))$ as infinity.

Comment: @A.S. thanks for commenting. I forgot to write it, but the question assumes that $X$ has finite moments of any order

Comment: Still, most likely they can grow faster than exponential or slower than exponential depending on how fast/slow $\bar F$ decays.

Comment: @A.S. you are probably right for the unbounded support case. However with finite support there is no "decay" so I still wonder whether there's a maximal growth rate.

Comment: If $|X|$ is supported on, say, $[a,b]$ and $f'_{|X|}(b)\in R$, then $r(k)\sim C\sqrt{\frac k {bf_{|X|}(b)}}$ by Laplaces' method matching your uniform result. If there is an atom at $b$ - your discrete result holds.

Comment: @A.S. Interesting application of Laplace method indeed, you can write it as an answer. Probably you meant $f(b)\in R$ (not $f'$). Do you think the same $O(\sqrt{k})$ rate still holds if $r(k)$ is redefined as $\frac{E[|X_k|^3]}{E[|X_k|^2]^{3/2}}$, where $X_k$ is any polynomial in $X$ of degree $k$?